# Entity Framework Core One to Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to build a phone list with Entity Framework Core. Whenever I try to run the commend: `Add-Migration "Initial"`

I get the following error: `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Member.MemberTeam' of type 'Team'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.`

Here are my models:

```
public class Member {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MemberName { get; set; }
        public string MemberTitle { get; set; }
        public Member MemberSupervisor { get; set; }
        public Team MemberTeam { get; set; }
    }

public class Team {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public Member TeamSupervisor { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Member> TeamMembers { get; set; }
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several relationships between `Team` and `Member` and from `Member` to `Member`. If you only had this model ...

```
public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public string MemberTitle { get; set; }
    public Team MemberTeam { get; set; }
}
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Member> TeamMembers { get; set; }
}
```

... EF wouldn't need any help. It would understand that `Team.TeamMembers` and `Member.MemberTeam` are two ends of one association.

Now if you only add ...

```
public Member TeamSupervisor { get; set; }
```

... EF has to choose if this is the reverse end of a one-to-one association with `MemberTeam`, or a new association besides the one-to-many association. However, EF doesn't choose for you, you have to instruct it unambiguously, by mapping the associations explicitly. For example (in your `DbContext` subclass):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<Team>().Property(a => a.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
    mb.Entity<Team>().HasMany(t => t.TeamMembers).WithOne(m => m.MemberTeam);
    mb.Entity<Team>().HasOne(t => t.TeamSupervisor).WithMany()
                     .HasForeignKey("SupervisorId");

    mb.Entity<Member>().Property(a => a.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
    mb.Entity<Member>().HasOne(m => m.MemberSupervisor).WithMany()
                       .HasForeignKey("SupervisorId");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I am still trying to learn C# and ASP.Net.